# How to install Nokogiri on Manjaro

Tags: ruby, linux, nokogiri, archlinux, manjaro

I installed, and reinstalled, Nokogiri multiple times, with and without `sudo`, and when running `bundle install` I get in my console:

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.10.7
Installing nokogiri 1.10.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/april/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7/ext/nokogiri
/home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby -I /home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r
./siteconf20200331-50466-133fhom.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an
executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:574:in `block in try_compile'
    from /home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:521:in `with_werror'
    from /home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:574:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:162:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /home/april/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:632:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:161:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:416:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/april/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.7/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/april/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/april/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.7'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  activeadmin_addons was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
    xdan-datetimepicker-rails was resolved to 2.5.4, which depends on
      rails was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
        actioncable was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
          actionpack was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
            actionview was resolved to 5.1.5, which depends on
              rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
                nokogiri
```

I also tried re-installing libxml2 and libxslt and I still keep running into this issue.

Comment: Do you have the ruby development headers? What is in the mkmf.log?

Comment: follow the steps for [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

Comment: Manjaro : `# pacman -S ruby` .... `gem install nokogiri` : Successfully installed nokogiri-1.10.9